# Background Service that checks if Messages, Contacts or Gallery is clicked Android

Tags: android

I need a background Service for my application that runs in background and checks when gallery, messages or contacts is clicked, it launches my application instead of launching gallery, messages or contacts. I have searched a lot but haven't found perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try IntentFilter?

```
<activity android:name="MyGalleryActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**UPD**
Please see theese links for more information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

Comment: I haven't tried it but can you please guide me with it

Comment: to extend this answer: you cannot launch your application *instead* of some other, since this would be malicious behavior. You can detect if some system app like Gallery was started and launch your app in addition, but this would be considered as spam by most users. Using `intent-filter` will inform the system that your app can handle these specific actions and offer your app among other apps that can handle the same action